# A question about the verb « s’apparenter »

Tags: verbes

On Larousse, it states that one of the definitions of *« s’apparenter »* is

> [En parlant de deux listes, de deux partis, être liés par un accord d'apparentement.](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/s_apparenter/4643?q=apparenter#4624)

I’m having a hard time understanding this definition (because of the word *apparentement*) therefore, could somebody translate just this definition please.

Thank you so much for your help guys!

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a form of political alliance that is allowed in some electoral systems: two political parties will do their own campaigns separately, but agree to group the votes in their favor, so that these votes are counted as if they were one party. They will then assign seats or mandates according to their respective electoral weights.

This is a very general definition, every system that allows it has its own technicalities. See [here](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparentement#Apparentement_%C3%A9lectoral).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @Greg ! This explanation is super clear.  However, although I understand your explanation I don’t see how could use this particular  definition of *« s’apparenter »* (or is it *« être apparenté »*) in a sentence. :/ Thus, if it wouldn’t be too much trouble, please could you use this particular definition of *« s’apparenter »* (or *« être apparenté »*) in some simple sentences please. 

Comment: Also, what is the English equivalent of *« l’appartement »* ?

Comment: 1) *le parti A est apparenté au parti B pour cette élection* or *le parti A a décidé de s'apparenter au parti B* or with a past participle used as adjective *députés du parti A et apparentés* (meaning, MPs that belong to party A or to parties allied with this party as part of an *apparentement*) 2) do you mean *appartement* or *apparentement* ?